# Composer Equivalent in JAVA?

Tags: java, composer-php

I currently moving to java from PHP.
Is there any tools equivalent like [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) in PHP for JAVA?

Composer is a command line tools for easily download other library and put that in our local project.

Comment: Have you tried building your project with [tag:maven]?

Comment: @Mureinik No, i really new to java :)

Comment: Maven is your godsend for implementing libraries. You just add the dependency to your pom.xml and boom.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most popular tools for that are: [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), [Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/), [Grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html), [Gradle](https://gradle.org), [Bundlr](http://blog.bundlr.com/), [SBT](https://www.scala-sbt.org/), [Leiningen](https://leiningen.org/), but they're keeping dependencies for all projects in one folder. [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) keeps dependencies inside a project, in a subdirectory.

You can browse content of main Maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: What if the dependency itself is a self developed library?
e.g. I have a java jar 'abc' and this 'abc' is a dependency to my actual project. I want to use a specific branch of 'abc' (i.e. checking out the right branch, building it, and installing it so that it could be used in the main project).
see my question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010168/gradle-dependency-management-with-feature-branch

Comment: In Composer there's -alias for that, in Maven-based dependency management there's -version (a number) and optional -type and -attempt (those can be words, any, except date or "SNAPSHOT") which can be used to name the feature you've added.