# Using maven for php

Tags: php, maven, maven-3

I'm java developer and I often use maven in my project to manage project structure,build lifecycle,dependencies, documentation (and other things). Now I'm starting to developing a php webapp and I would want to use maven in this project [Maven for PHP](http://www.php-maven.org/). Now I trying to make a project from [PHP web projects](http://www.php-maven.org/tags/2.0.2/php-web-5min.html) but I'm not able to do this and I got the following exception:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does
>   not exist (org.phpmaven:php5-web-archetype:2.0.2)

Now in addition to the problem I described above, I want to ask you:

Is maven the correct tool of project managment also in php? Otherwise What's tools do you suggest?

Comment: same problem here. Any luck?

Comment: Maven is primarily for java but not for PHP,  the composer can be used to achieve desired maven tasks for PHP

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844103/composer-equivalent-in-java

Answer (score 3):

The archetype repository on nexus no longer exists, this is why your mvn generate will fail. I have now searched for days to find a good set of documents that will help me setup a php5 environment in Eclipse with phpunit unit tests that work from a maven life cycle. No luck so far. So I'm getting closer to the conclusion that maven is fine, great perhaps even for Java but kind of not-the-right-tool for php.

Comment: Also I have the same opinion, maven is really great for java but not for php